# Field id expected a number but got <Cart: John's cart>

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I have this view I would like to create a cart or update the entries if the cart is already created and if a product is already in the cart then just update its quantity. I am getting an error saying Field id expected a number but got <Cart: John's cart>. Why is the id field even mentioned when I specifically put cart to filter, because I do not have the id of the Entry

```
class CreateCart(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = CartSerializer   
    def post(self, request):
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.data.get("user"))
        total = request.data.get("carttotal")
        usercart = Cart.objects.update_or_create(user=user, cart_total=total)
        products = request.data.getlist("products")
        for product in products:
            obj = json.loads(product)
            id = obj.get("id")
            qty = obj.get("qty")
            product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
            exists = Entry.objects.all().filter(cart=usercart, product=product)
            if exists:
                exists.quantity = qty
            else:
                Entry.objects.create(product=product, cart=usercart, quantity=qty)
        return Response("Items added or updated", status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

This line Django is complaining about:

```
exists = Entry.objects.all().filter(cart=usercart, product=product)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, the [`update_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) method returns a tuple containing the object and a boolean value indicating whether it was created or updated. So, you should unpack the tuple to get the actual `Cart` instance as:

```py
usercart, created = Cart.objects.update_or_create(user=user, cart_total=total)
```

Comment: Ok thank you at least the error is gone but the cart is not updating in the DB, so am I using the wrong generic DRF view?

Comment: It updates if I add a product but if I change the quantity of any of the products then I get a duplicate key violation. django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "carts_cart_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(33) already exists. Why am I gettting this error pls? I thought that is what update does?

Comment: @crawlingdev The cart is not updating since you haven't saved it using `save()` method so there should be `exists.save()` also after `exists.quantity = qty`.

Comment: Ok thanks I get that I have to save I forgot about that, but even with adding save I still get the duplicate key violation if I try and update the quantity of any product. And exists.save gives an error QuerySet object has no attribute save. So if I get the object first is it going to make two database calls?

Comment: But no matter what I still get the duplicate key violation. I thought that is what update is for?

Comment: don't worry I solved it but your input helped me so thank you